# Hosting NodeJS and ReactJS Application in AWS using elastic bean stalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What's the process to host React Application on AWS using elastic bean stalk, CI/CD process.

Project Folder Structure:

`App`

---> `api`

---> `infrastructure`

---> `web/myApp`

The App folder has **api** which is backend express server. **myApp** folder has frontend ReactJS application.